# Download Pdf from server in Vue js using fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file, pdf, download

Here is the fetch function, that gets file contents (The actual PDF file) as response.

```
            fetch(url, {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            }).then((response) => {
              console.log(response)
            return response.json()
            }).catch((ex) => {
                console.log(ex)
            })
```

But couldn’t convert it to json to read the actual content. Instead I face this error when doing response.json()

*"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%', "%PDF-1.7
%"... is not valid JSON"*

How do i convert it to Json so that i make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out on my own. Changing response.json() to response.blob() fixed my problem.

```
fetch(url, { credentials: 'same-origin' })
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
  return response.blob()
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.log(ex)
})
```